# Azure VM provisioning from custom VHD using saltstack

Tags: azure, salt-stack

I am using salt cloud profile to provision vm on azure from custom vhd but it is taking around 40 min then failing on saying "

> Provisioning failed. OS Provisioning for VM 'customtestpsvm' did not
>   finish in the allotted time. The VM may still finish provisioning
>   successfully. Please check provisioning state later..
>   OSProvisioningTimedOut

"

The steps performed by me are as follows:-

1. Create azure vm on portal.
2. RDP into that vm and do required modifications(open port and all) and sysprep.
3. Copy the OSDisk VHD of VM to blob storage using Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy powershell command.
4. Wait for the copy to complete.
5. Then using the uri of the vhd(in blob storage) as Image in salt cloud profile.

The salt profile i am using is as follows :-

```
azure-win:
  cleanup_data_disks: True
  cleanup_disks: True
  cleanup_interfaces: True
  cleanup_vhds: True
  deploy: False
  expire_group_cache: 86400
  expire_interface_cache: 3600
  expire_network_cache: 3600
  expire_offer_cache: 604800
  expire_publisher_cache: 604800
  expire_sku_cache: 604800
  expire_subnet_cache: 3600
  expire_version_cache: 604800
  image: https://crimasterdisks791.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/custompsimage.vhd
  location: EastUS
  network: AzureARM-SanRamon-New
  network_resource_group: AzureARM-SanRamon-New-ResGrp
  os_disk_size_gb: 140
  provider: P_Azure
  resource_group: AzureARM-SanRamon-New-ResGrp
  security_group: cri-azure
  size: Basic_A1
  win_password: Spam99$$
  win_username: azureuser
  storage_account: crimasterdisks791
  subnet: ARM-Subnet1
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the suggestions mentioned in the below links.
https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/38907 
https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/41315

Custom Salt execution, state, and other modules can be distributed to Salt minions using the Salt file server.
Under the root of any environment defined via the file_roots option on the master server directories corresponding to the type of module can be used.
The directories are prepended with an underscore: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/file_server/dynamic-modules.html

Azure is a cloud service by Microsoft providing virtual machines, SQL services, media services, and more. This document describes how to use Salt Cloud to create a virtual machine on Azure, with Salt installed. 
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/cloud/azure.html

Provisioning operation. That is the reason you were experiencing this issue and this might be because of several reasons ( depending on the VM configurations, location, Size)

Could you try importing the following: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/cloud/clouds/azurearm.py#L77-L112
Those are all of the required dependencies for azurearm. So this will help narrow down if you have the correct dependencies.
You can test these imports by running python -c 'import azure.storage' for those imports on your salt-cloud box. And if you get an import error on any of those then you are missing that dependency.

Comment: The provisioning is going fine when i am using Marketplace image.

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved by following the steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sa-copy-generalized?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json
But to make it work one more change is required in salt code,

For custom image the os_type parmaeter is dependent on win_installer parameter ,

```
if vm_['image'].startswith('http'):
# https://{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net/{path}/{vhd}
source_image = VirtualHardDisk(vm_['image'])
img_ref = None
if win_installer:
os_type = 'Windows'
else:
os_type = 'Linux'
```

But if we make deploy as False, we don`t give win_installer and in case of windows custom images also the os_type gets set to Linux and that is why it was failing.

I made some changes in code n gave os_type directly in profile to make it work